# Convert text input to JSON and copy result to clipboard with one button

Tags: javascript, html, json

This code contains two buttons, the first one submits some text to be converted into JSON and the the second one copies the result to the clipboard. It would be great to be able to do both with one click. Is there a way to combine the two so that when I click the submit button the JSON is automatically copied to the clipboard?

```
<html>
<body>
    
<form id='foobar'>
    <label for='event_name'>Event Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="event_name" name='event_name' value="Concert"/>
    <label for='venue_name'>Venue Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="venue_name" name="venue_name" value="Theater" />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>

<pre id='output'>Input some value and submit</pre>

<script>
    
document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const data = Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce((memo, pair) => ({
    ...memo,
    [pair[0]]: pair[1],
  }), {});
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
});

// Copy button


    function selectElementContents(el) {
    // Copy textarea, pre, div, etc.
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        // IE
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.select();
        textRange.execCommand("Copy");
    } 
    else if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        // Non-Internet Explorer
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }
    }
} // end function selectElementContents(el)

function make_copy_button(el) {
    var copy_btn = document.createElement('input');
    copy_btn.type = "button";
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(copy_btn, el.nextSibling);
    copy_btn.onclick = function() {
        selectElementContents(el);
    };

    if (document.queryCommandSupported("copy") || parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./)[2]) >= 42) {
        // Copy works with Internet Explorer 4+, Chrome 42+, Firefox 41+, Opera 29+
        copy_btn.value = "Copy to Clipboard";
    }
    else {
        // Select only for Safari and older Chrome, Firefox and Opera
        copy_btn.value = "Select All (then press Ctrl + C to Copy)";
    }
}

make_copy_button(document.getElementById("output"));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can simply call `selectElementContents()` function after the `innerHTML` is applied to the `output` and then send that `element` to your function to be able to copy the `content` on `clicking` submit button.

In addition, with one `button` only you do need the other `two` functions to create `button` manually. As the `results` can now achieved with one button which is when you hit `submit` - The copy Command will be applied to the whole `JSON` output.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let output = document.getElementById('output')
document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const data = Array.from(formData.entries()).reduce((memo, pair) => ({
    ...memo,
    [pair[0]]: pair[1],
  }), {});
  output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  selectElementContents(output) //copy to clipboard
});

// Copy to clipboard
function selectElementContents(el) {
  // Copy textarea, pre, div, etc.
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    // IE
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    textRange.select();
    textRange.execCommand("Copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    // Non-Internet Explorer
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    try {
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
      console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form id='foobar'>
    <label for='event_name'>Event Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="event_name" name='event_name' value="Concert" />
    <label for='venue_name'>Venue Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="venue_name" name="venue_name" value="Theater" />
    <input type='submit' value="Submit" />
  </form>

  <pre id='output'>Input some value and submit</pre>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A more concise example:

```
function copyJsonToClipboard() {
   //Example object
   const data = {
      eventName: "Concert",
      venueName: "Theater"
   };
   //Converting the object to JSON
   const json = JSON.stringify(data);
   //Copying the JSON to the clipboard
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(json);
}
```

See [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [clipboard.writeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText).

Comment: This example `object` will **fail** if OP has more inputs in the form OR if `inputs` are being added dynamically to the form for copying to clipboard. The code structure OP has currently will allows the OP to add more `inputs` to the form without modifying the JS which is very ideal - Just for your information.

Comment: The example above doesn't contain any form or input logic, so the thing you're describing isn't included here. I left this out on purpose to keep it concise.